# Problema com crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler

Estou tentando fazer um crowler simples que pega a temperatura, apenas para estudo, estou usando o [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) para ler a página, porém na função file_get_html do link acima, apresenta alguns erros, e eu não estou entendendo o porque. Os códigos que uso em `temperatura.class` foram tirado desse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4OriipJjtI). Inclusive estou usando o mesmo [link](http://www.tempoagora.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/sp/Cotia/) para a busca da temperatura, mudando apenas o lugar. Uso php 7.2.

(A linha 75 estará marcada no código).

1° erro:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in C:\wamp64\www\crowler_php\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

2° erro:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in C:\wamp64\www\crowler_php\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

3° erro:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '>' in C:\wamp64\www\crowler_php\temperatura.class.php on line 26

temperatura.class:

```
require_once './simple_html_dom.php';

class Temperatura {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->getTemperatura("http://www.tempoagora.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/sp/Cotia/");
    }

    public function getTemperatura($url){

        $html = file_get_html($url);

        preg_match_all('/<div class=\"item\">(.*?)<\/div/>', $html, $resultado);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resultado);
    }
}

$t = new Temperatura();
```

O código de `simple_html_dom.php` está [aqui](https://gist.github.com/LeTarzan/6eeb1dd810c1a0356538461dd271d9b4)

Comment: No 3o. erro faltou colocar o `/` no final da expressão regular: `preg_match_all('/<div class=\"item\">(.*?)<\/div/>/', $html, $resultado);`... onde vc colocou no lugar errado depois de "div": `<\/div/>`

Comment: Continuou o mesmo erro..